# Automatically scroll to bottom as elements are added to dom

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

I am using Polymer data-binding. I add elements to an array and it, in turn, adds elements to the DOM which get displayed vertically.

I would like the page to scroll as elements are added but only if the current scroll height is at the bottom of the page.

Rough sudo code:

```
if (scrollToBottomEanbled && atBottomOfPage) {
    window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

But given that Polymer works with templates and shadow DOMS etc, I don't know which event I should be attaching this code to?

Comment: How about putting that on `data-changed` listeners?

Comment: How about the `dom-change` event: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-change - guess you'll also have to wait one refresh cycle `this.async` and then scroll down...